# Using pyparsing to parse a word escape-split over multiple lines

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse words which can be broken up over multiple lines with a backslash-newline combination ("`\\n`") using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). Here's what I have done:

```
from pyparsing import *

continued_ending = Literal('\\') + lineEnd
word = Word(alphas)
split_word = word + Suppress(continued_ending)
multi_line_word = Forward()
multi_line_word << (word | (split_word + multi_line_word))

print multi_line_word.parseString(
'''super\\
cali\\
fragi\\
listic''')
```

The output I get is `['super']`, while the expected output is `['super', 'cali', fragi', 'listic']`. Better still would be all of them joined as one word (which I think I can just do with `multi_line_word.parseAction(lambda t: ''.join(t))`.

I tried looking at this code in [pyparsing helper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing_helper), but it gives me an error, `maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

**EDIT 2009-11-15:** I realized later that pyparsing gets a little generous with regards to white space, and that leads to some poor assumptions that what I thought I was parsing for was a lot looser. That is to say, we want to see no white space between any of the portions of the word, the escape, and the EOL character.

I realized that the little example string above is insufficient as a test case, so I wrote the following unit tests. Code that passes these tests should be able to match what I intuitively think of as a escape-split word—and *only* an escape-split word. They will not match a basic word that is not escape-split. We can—and I believe should—use a different grammatical construct for that. This keeps it all tidy having the two separate.

```
import unittest
import pyparsing

# Assumes you named your module 'multiline.py'
import multiline

class MultiLineTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_continued_ending(self):

        case = '\\\n'
        expected = ['\\', '\n']
        result = multiline.continued_ending.parseString(case).asList()
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)


    def test_continued_ending_space_between_parse_error(self):

        case = '\\ \n'
        self.assertRaises(
            pyparsing.ParseException,
            multiline.continued_ending.parseString,
            case
        )


    def test_split_word(self):

        cases = ('shiny\\', 'shiny\\\n', ' shiny\\')
        expected = ['shiny']
        for case in cases:
            result = multiline.split_word.parseString(case).asList()
            self.assertEqual(result, expected)


    def test_split_word_no_escape_parse_error(self):

        case = 'shiny'
        self.assertRaises(
            pyparsing.ParseException,
            multiline.split_word.parseString,
            case
        )


    def test_split_word_space_parse_error(self):

        cases = ('shiny \\', 'shiny\r\\', 'shiny\t\\', 'shiny\\ ')
        for case in cases:
            self.assertRaises(
                pyparsing.ParseException,
                multiline.split_word.parseString,
                case
            )


    def test_multi_line_word(self):

        cases = (
                'shiny\\',
                'shi\\\nny',
                'sh\\\ni\\\nny\\\n',
                ' shi\\\nny\\',
                'shi\\\nny '
                'shi\\\nny captain'
        )
        expected = ['shiny']
        for case in cases:
            result = multiline.multi_line_word.parseString(case).asList()
            self.assertEqual(result, expected)


    def test_multi_line_word_spaces_parse_error(self):

        cases = (
                'shi \\\nny',
                'shi\\ \nny',
                'sh\\\n iny',
                'shi\\\n\tny',
        )
        for case in cases:
            self.assertRaises(
                pyparsing.ParseException,
                multiline.multi_line_word.parseString,
                case
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After poking around for a bit more, I came upon [this help thread](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/message/view/home/11262229) where there was this notable bit

> I often see inefficient grammars when
>   someone implements a pyparsing grammar
>   directly from a BNF definition. BNF
>   does not have a concept of "one or
>   more" or "zero or more" or
>   "optional"...

With that, I got the idea to change these two lines

```
multi_line_word = Forward()
multi_line_word << (word | (split_word + multi_line_word))
```

To

```
multi_line_word = ZeroOrMore(split_word) + word
```

This got it to output what I was looking for: `['super', 'cali', fragi', 'listic']`.

Next, I added a parse action that would join these tokens together:

```
multi_line_word.setParseAction(lambda t: ''.join(t))
```

This gives a final output of `['supercalifragilistic']`.

The take home message I learned is that one doesn't simply [walk into Mordor](http://waxy.org/random/images/weblog/mortor.gif).

Just kidding.

The take home message is that one can't simply implement a one-to-one translation of BNF with pyparsing. Some tricks with using the iterative types should be called into use.

**EDIT 2009-11-25:** To compensate for the more strenuous test cases, I modified the code to the following:

```
no_space = NotAny(White(' \t\r'))
# make sure that the EOL immediately follows the escape backslash
continued_ending = Literal('\\') + no_space + lineEnd
word = Word(alphas)
# make sure that the escape backslash immediately follows the word
split_word = word + NotAny(White()) + Suppress(continued_ending)
multi_line_word = OneOrMore(split_word + NotAny(White())) + Optional(word)
multi_line_word.setParseAction(lambda t: ''.join(t))
```

This has the benefit of making sure that no space comes between any of the elements (with the exception of newlines after the escaping backslashes).

Comment: Using `Combine` also enforces no intervening whitespace.

Comment: Interesting. tried
`multi_line_word = Combine(Combine(OneOrMore(split_word)) + Optional(word))`
but it breaks on the `'sh\\\n iny'` case in that it doesn't raise an exception, but instead returns `['sh']`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, your word is not just letters spanning a '\'-newline, but there is that space in there before the letter 'i', which counts as a word break, so Combine stops after the 'sh'.  You *can* modify Combine with an adjacent=False constructor argument, but beware - you might end up sucking up the entire file as a single word!  Or you can redefine your definition of continued_ending to include any whitespace after the lineEnd, if you want to also collapse any leading spaces.

Comment: I would prefer `multi_line_word.parseString('sh\\\n iny')` raise `ParseException`, not identify `'sh'` as its token. In this case `'sh'` and `'iny'` are two words, not parts of a broken word, because the `'iny'` part is not contiguous with the EOL. Thus, `multi_line_word` shouldn't recognize it. It should throw up its hands and say, "This is not a valid broken-up word!"

Answer (score 5):

You are pretty close with your code.  Any of these mods would work:

```
# '|' means MatchFirst, so you had a left-recursive expression
# reversing the order of the alternatives makes this work
multi_line_word << ((split_word + multi_line_word) | word)

# '^' means Or/MatchLongest, but beware using this inside a Forward
multi_line_word << (word ^ (split_word + multi_line_word))

# an unusual use of delimitedList, but it works
multi_line_word = delimitedList(word, continued_ending)

# in place of your parse action, you can wrap in a Combine
multi_line_word = Combine(delimitedList(word, continued_ending))
```

As you found in your pyparsing googling, BNF->pyparsing translations should be done with a special view to using pyparsing features in place of BNF, um, shortcomings.  I was actually in the middle of composing a longer answer, going into more of the BNF translation issues, but you have already found this material (on the wiki, I assume).